# Quicker way to edit modifiers

Tags: expresso-store, expresso

Wondering if there was quicker way to update Product Modifiers.

We have a lot of products which are the same price but bit of a pain having to update every price modifier 1 by 1.

Anyone used Zenbu to maybe mass edit these. Don't think it's supported.

Comment: Zenbu does have extension hooks that you could use to create an extension for Store & Zenbu to allow this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say, but in a word: nope.